# Multi Frames having images in iOS

Tags: ios

I want to create an iOS application having multi frame something similar to this .http://multiframe.tumblr.com/page/6  Does somebody has any pointers

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where did you get stuck? If you haven't tried anything already, maybe consider doing some research on Google, and having a go yourself, and then returning when you get stuck.

Answer (score 1):

This is simple stuff, I'll give you an example but to practice this and learn more about it you'll want to look into UIImageView's, CGRectMake, and subview layouts:

```
[self.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
UIImageView *image1 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"myImage1"]];
UIImageView *image2 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"myImage2"]];
UIImageView *image3 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"myImage3"]];

[image1 setFrame:CGRectMake(20, 20, 280, 133)];
[image2 setFrame:CGRectMake(20, 173, 280, 133)];
[image3 setFrame:CGRectMake(20, 20, 280, 326)];

[self.view addSubview:image1];
[self.view addSubview:image2];
[self.view addSubview:image3];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're enrolled in the iOS Developer Program, have a look at the WWDC presentations on UICollectionView - that provides the facility to create grid-based layouts in a similar way to UITableView.

Comment: iOS 6 features are still under NDA.

Comment: ...which is why the OP will need to be enrolled in the Dev Program